# Most efficient structure for quick access to a random element + the last element on one criteria

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, data-structures

We have a function that is informed that we received an item for a specific timestamp.

The purpose of this is to wait that for one specific timestamp, we wait that we receive every item that we are expecting, then push the notification further once we are "synchronized" with all items.

Currently, we have a `Dictionary<DateTime, TimeSlot>` to store the non-synchronized TimeSlot(TimeSlot = list of all items we received for a specific timestamp).

```
//Let's assume that this method is not called concurrently, and only once per "MyItem"
public void HandleItemReceived(DateTime timestamp, MyItem item){
    TimeSlot slot;
    //_pendingTimeSlot is a Dictionary<DateTime,TimeSlot>
    if(!_pendingTimeSlot.TryGetValue(timestamp, out slot)){
        slot = new TimeSlot(timestamp);
        _pendingTimeSlot.Add(timestamp,slot );

        //Sometimes we don't receive all the items for one timestamps, which may leads to some ghost-incomplete TimeSlot
        if(_pendingTimeSlot.Count>_capacity){
            TimeSlot oldestTimeSlot = _pendingTimeSlot.OrderBy(t=>t.Key).Select(t=>t.Value).First();
            _pendingTimeSlot.Remove(oldestTimeSlot.TimeStamp);
            //Additional work here to log/handle this case
        }
    }
    slot.HandleItemReceived(item);
    if(slot.IsComplete){
        PushTimeSlotSyncronized(slot);
        _pendingTimeSlot.Remove(slot.TimeStamp);
    }
}
```

We have severals instances of this "Synchronizer" in parallels for differents group of items.

It's working fine, except when the system is under heavy loads, we have more incomplete TimeSlot, and the application uses a lot more CPU. The profiler seems to indicate that the `Compare` of the LINQ query is taking a lot of time(most of the time). So I'm trying to find some structure to hold those references(replace the dictionary)

Here are some metrics:

- We have several(variable, but between 10 to 20) instances of this Synchronizer
- The current maximum capacity(`_capacity`) of the synchronizer is 500 items
- The shortest interval that we can have between two different timestamp is 100ms(so 10 new Dictionary entry per seconds for each Synchronizer)(most case are more 1 item/second)
- For each timestamp, we expect to receive 300-500 items.

So we will do, for one Synchronizer, per second(worst case):

- 1 Add
- 500 Get
- 3-5 Sorts

What would be my best move? I thought to the `SortedDictionary` But I didn't find any documentation showing me how to take the first element according to the key.

Comment: I don't think this is opinion-based -- algorithmic complexity's a measurable quantity.

Comment: Slightly tangentially: https://rawgit.com/rehansaeed/.NET-Big-O-Algorithm-Complexity-Cheat-Sheet/master/Cheat%20Sheet.html

Comment: The best solution is to use a List<> instead of Dictionary.  I would add items into list in time order so there is no need to perform a sort.  I would check the last item in list with item to add to make sure the new item is later than last item.  If not, work backwards from end of list until new item is put into list in order.

Comment: Is `_pendingTimeSlot` really a dictionary? I'm asking because there is no `TryGet` method and the result of the `OrderBy(..).First()` should be 'KeyValuePair<DateTime, TimeSlot>', not  `TimeSlot`.

Comment: @IvanStoev Yes it's a dictionary, but I had to simplify a lot this code to have a readeable form, so it's not my real code. But you're right, it's the `TryGetValue` method that is called, and the order by should select the `Value`. I will update that

Comment: @jdweng How a list could be more efficient when we do 500 get of non-sequential element(my `TryGetValue` in the code)? It would mean that I've to iterate on each of them. Please note that the last item is maybe not the "oldest", since we may not receive all of them in the correct order(it's coming from different devices on the network).

Comment: A complete sort takes average (N**2)/2 compares.  You don't want to do a complete sort everytime a new item is added.  It is inefficient.  When you have a large list in real time and data is coming some what sequentially it is better to add near the end to a list.   To do complete sort with 500 items you will need to do an average of 500/2 compares.  Starting at end of a sequential list will reduce the number of compares significantly.

Comment: @jdweng But my last items are (usually) the biggest one, it does not count for something? Your (N**2)/2 is right when the array is totally unsorted, no? I guess there is some kind of bubble sorts( with only the item I just added)

Comment: I'm using a modified bubble sort.  Just starting at the end since I know the new items are going to be added near the end of the list provided new items are coming approximately in order.   Size of items shouldn't make a difference.  You are sorting by timestamp.  You have a structure with two object : DateTime and Data.  The sort is only looking at the DateTime and the sort is using pointers to structure (so size isn't a factor).

Comment: @jdweng can you maybe make a solution proposal with an small example?

Comment: Added solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you can try is eliminating the `OrderBy` - all you need is the minimum key, no need to sort for getting that:

```
if (_pendingTimeSlot.Count > _capacity) {
    // No Enumerable.Min(DateTime), so doing it manually
    var oldestTimeStamp = DateTime.MaxValue;
    foreach (var key in _pendingTimeSlot.Keys)
        if (oldestTimeStamp > key) oldestTimestamp = key;
    _pendingTimeSlot.Remove(oldestTimeStamp);
    //Additional work here to log/handle this case
}
```

What about `SortedDictionary`, it is an option for sure, although it will consume much more memory. Since it's sorted, you can use simply `sortedDictionary.First()` to take the key value pair with the minimum key (hence the oldest element in your case).

**UPDATE:** Here is a hybrid approach using dictionary for fast lookups and ordered double linked list for the other scenarios.

```
class MyItem
{
    // ...
}
class TimeSlot
{
    public readonly DateTime TimeStamp;
    public TimeSlot(DateTime timeStamp)
    {
        TimeStamp = timeStamp;
        // ...
    }
    public bool IsComplete = false;
    public void HandleItemReceived(MyItem item)
    {
        // ...
    }
    // Dedicated members
    public TimeSlot PrevPending, NextPending;
}
class Synhronizer
{
    const int _capacity = 500;
    Dictionary<DateTime, TimeSlot> pendingSlotMap = new Dictionary<DateTime, TimeSlot>(_capacity + 1);
    TimeSlot firstPending, lastPending;

    //Let's assume that this method is not called concurrently, and only once per "MyItem"
    public void HandleItemReceived(DateTime timeStamp, MyItem item)
    {
        TimeSlot slot;
        if (!pendingSlotMap.TryGetValue(timeStamp, out slot))
        {
            slot = new TimeSlot(timeStamp);
            Add(slot);
            //Sometimes we don't receive all the items for one timestamps, which may leads to some ghost-incomplete TimeSlot
            if (pendingSlotMap.Count > _capacity)
            {
                // Remove the oldest, which in this case is the first
                var oldestSlot = firstPending;
                Remove(oldestSlot);
                //Additional work here to log/handle this case
            }
        }
        slot.HandleItemReceived(item);
        if (slot.IsComplete)
        {
            PushTimeSlotSyncronized(slot);
            Remove(slot);
        }
    }

    void Add(TimeSlot slot)
    {
        pendingSlotMap.Add(slot.TimeStamp, slot);
        // Starting from the end, search for a first slot having TimeStamp < slot.TimeStamp
        // If the TimeStamps almost come in order, this is O(1) op.
        var after = lastPending;
        while (after != null && after.TimeStamp > slot.TimeStamp)
            after = after.PrevPending;
        // Insert the new slot after the found one (if any).
        if (after != null)
        {
            slot.PrevPending = after;
            slot.NextPending = after.NextPending;
            after.NextPending = slot;
            if (slot.NextPending == null) lastPending = slot;
        }
        else
        {
            if (firstPending == null)
                firstPending = lastPending = slot;
            else
            {
                slot.NextPending = firstPending;
                firstPending.PrevPending = slot;
                firstPending = slot;
            }
        }
    }

    void Remove(TimeSlot slot)
    {
        pendingSlotMap.Remove(slot.TimeStamp);
        if (slot.NextPending != null)
            slot.NextPending.PrevPending = slot.PrevPending;
        else
            lastPending = slot.PrevPending;
        if (slot.PrevPending != null)
            slot.PrevPending.NextPending = slot.NextPending;
        else
            firstPending = slot;
        slot.PrevPending = slot.NextPending = null;
    }

    void PushTimeSlotSyncronized(TimeSlot slot)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Some additional usages:

Iterating from oldest to newest:

```
for (var slot = firstPending; slot != null; slot = slot.NextPending)
{
    // do something
}
```

Iterating from oldest to newest and removing items based on a criteria:

```
for (TimeSlot slot = firstPending, nextSlot; slot != null; slot = nextSlot)
{
    nextSlot = slot.NextPending;
    if (ShouldRemove(slot))
        Remove(slot);
}
```

Same for reverse scenarios, but using `lastPending` and `PrevPending` members instead.

Comment: I really like the idea, it would work for the case I explained, but we have an other case: Sometimes we have to inform that timeslots are complete in the order. I mean, we have to wait that T1 is complete before informing that T2 is complete, so maybe when T1 is complete, we can also inform that T2/3/...5 are also complete. Using your way will imply that we will iterate 5(in this example) time to our dictionary. Do you still think we would benefit of your implementation(against a `SortedDictionary`) ?

Comment: I was also wondering: Since the new items have to be placed usually at the end(because more recent), is that quicker to insert data?

Comment: @J4N It was based on the use cases in the question. As you know, there is no perfect data structure for everything, and your additional case changes significantly the requirements. So you definitely need some sort of a sorted  container. `SortedDictionary` is one of the options.  If you are almost always adding at the end and almost always removing from the beginning of the list, some custom data structure could perform better. Do you have other use cases? Also is it allowed to add some dedicated members to the `TimeSlot` class?

Comment: No, the only case I didn't mention initially is the case when we try to remove the X oldest data(sorry, I didn't think it would influence a lot). TimeSlot can definitely be modified as we want. What kind of dedicated members you think of?

Comment: @J4N I'm thinking of adding 2 `TimeSlot` fields to be used for a double linked pending list.

Comment: And what would be linked? The previous/next one in the time order?

Comment: @J4N I've updated the answer with the implementation based on that idea.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will put it to the test. I'm just a little bit afraid that the operation that we will do the most(add one item inside an existing TimeSlot inside the buffer will be quite slow, even if we earn a little time everytime we add a brand new TimeSlot.

Comment: @J4N Yeah, sorry, I totally overlooked the lookup part which is dominating in your use case. See the update for a better approach.

Comment: Really nice solution, thank you, I will definitely adapt it to my real scenario

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple sample.  The insert method in a list eliminates swapping elements.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Data> inputs = new List<Data>() {
                new Data() { date = DateTime.Parse("10/22/15 6:00AM"), data = "abc"},
                new Data() { date = DateTime.Parse("10/22/15 4:00AM"), data = "def"},
                new Data() { date = DateTime.Parse("10/22/15 6:30AM"), data = "ghi"},
                new Data() { date = DateTime.Parse("10/22/15 12:00AM"), data = "jkl"},
                new Data() { date = DateTime.Parse("10/22/15 3:00AM"), data = "mno"},
                new Data() { date = DateTime.Parse("10/22/15 2:00AM"), data = "pqr"},
            };

            Data data = new Data();
            foreach (Data input in inputs)
            {
                data.Add(input);
            }
        }
    }
    public class Data
    {
        public static List<Data> sortedData = new List<Data>();
        public DateTime date { get; set; }
        public string data { get; set;}


        public void Add(Data newData)
        {
            if(sortedData.Count == 0)
            {
                sortedData.Add(newData);
            }
            else
            {
               Boolean added = false;
               for(int index = sortedData.Count - 1; index >= 0; index--)
               {
                   if(newData.date > sortedData[index].date)
                   {
                       sortedData.Insert(index + 1, newData);
                       added = true;
                       break;
                   }
               }
               if (added == false)
               {
                   sortedData.Insert(0, newData);
               }
            }
        }
    }

}​
```

Comment: But in fact in the case I explain, I will have a lot of  entries for each timestamp, so I've to be able to add multiple data to each timestamp(in my example, the class containing all the items is called `TimeSlot`. It implies that I've to retrieve a lot of time(most of the time) a specific `TimeSlot` for a given timestamp, then add my data to it. I've the impression that having to retrieve 500x the timeslot for each timestamp will be slow.

Comment: Then string data becomes List<string> data. What criteria are you going to use to retrieve data.  I think in your case the insertion is real time but extracting doesn't need to be done in real time?  The most important factor is being able to store the data in real time.  So you need an efficient storage algorithm.  It would be nice to store data orderly if you have the overhead.  You may not have the overhead so storing in time order may be the best you can achieve.  You need to check performance before determining best method.

Comment: Yeah, but check my code, to be able to add some value to the `List<String>` I've to be able to retrieve this list first to add the item into it. I've ~500 items to add per timeslot

Comment: The List<string> can be made into a dictionary if you have sufficient processing time.  You have to make that decision.  With Real Time Processing testing is always required and refinements are sometimes required before finalizing an application.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand. We don't receive all data for a given timestamp in the same call. Everytime we receive one data, we have to check if already have a TimeSlot for this time, and if it's the case, add the data to the existing timeslot. Otherwise, no synchronization would be needed